# Is it possible to set different UI theme for JQuery UI tooltip inside jquery function

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to set different theme for JQuery UI tooltip inside jquery function. I am using other UI themes for different controls on the same page, just wondering if there is any way to set different UI theme for tooltip, may be in the jquery tooltip function.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"  Text='label' title="<p>tooltip text</p>"></asp:Label></td>


$(function () {
    $('[title]').tooltip({
        content: function () {
            var element = $(this);
            return element.attr('title')
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to specify the class name in your initialization

```
$('[title]').tooltip({
      tooltipClass: "custom-tooltip-styling"
 });
```

You can create different `css classes` and use that differently according some condition.

More details about [tooltip css clss](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-tooltipClass)
More about tool tip [parameters](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: is it possible to directly reference UI theme inside the function

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />

Comment: @user1263981 what would be condition then? Though you can not do this. You can create and use different themes but that would be for whole page rather than individual element.